# Browser Bookmarklet - How to track browser history?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet, browser-history

There's a bunch of new services that, once installed, track your browser history. Like.fm, for instance, tracks all the songs you listen to.

How hard is this? How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarlet is only the snippet Javascrip code which you can execute on current page, once you leave this page, it will got away, then you need to run it again.

You can use bookmarklet to store current page information to cookie, when user goto another page and run the bookmarklet again, you can get the information stored in cookie.

That's about how bookmarklet works. hope it helps.